# Detect CSP violations with javascript

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

Is it possible to detect a Content Security Policy violation with javascript?

My CSP works and sends its reports, where I see that some urls are injected, probably by browser addons. I would like to display a hint to the user, that some addon tries to modify the page.

Can I somehow detect the aborted connection with javascript (which is itself whitelisted in the CSP of course)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [W3C CSP specification](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#report-violation), a violation triggers a `securitypolicyviolation` event. You can add an event listener for this.

```
document.addEventListener("securitypolicyviolation", function(e) {
    alert("Something is trying something bad!");
});
```

See the above link for the properties of this event.

In Firefox Release, you need to enable the `security.csp.enable_violation_events` preference to enable this feature. See [Experimental Features in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Experimental_features#Security) documentation.

Comment: Does this work for you in firefox? Chromium works, but firefox doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Experimental_features#Security It's not enabled by default in the released version, there's a preference setting to enable it.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped this would work cross browser, so I can notify users of my website of malicious extensions. I had several requests in my CSP log, where extensions tried to insert tracking code and similar.